# mysql data insert into table ..... help.....(UPDATED)

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have table called 'shipped_data'

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXBej.png

and need go get all 'caseNumbers' that match with the perticular column and export as a 'CSV' file. like this.

http://i54.tinypic.com/168ydmq.png

how can i do this scenario.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is something like this what you're looking for?

```
$casenumbers = array();
$query = "select caseNumber from shipped_data where [particular column]";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $casenumbers[]=$data['casenumber'];
}
$output = implode(',',$casenumbers);
```